# Android NDK with Linux: "ndk-build" command not found

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm new to Linux (Ubuntu) and I had a problem building the libraries in my project.
I added the android ndk to the PATH like this:

```
  export PATH=$PATH:/android-ndk-r9b
```

and to Eclipse

but when I try to use the

```
ndk-build
```

command, I get this output:

```
ndk-build: command not found
```

Any help?

Comment: yes, this is the right path

Comment: What happens if your invoke it by it's full, explicit path name - `/android-ndk-r9b/ndk-build`  or if you `ls -l /android-ndk-r9b/ndk-build`

Comment: "No such file or directory"

Comment: OK, I got it right,
the problem was that I didn't supply the right path, it was:

    /home/yonatan/android-ndk-r9b/

Comment: Please post this discovery as an answer and accept the latter, don't get good people in this community confused.

Answer (score 0):

Your PATH should include the root directory of your NDK:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/.../android-ndk-xxx
```